# How to re-ask for an interview when the recruiter returns from travelling?

Tags: professionalism, interviewing, hiring-process, internship, email

The email read: "Please contact me when I return from traveling on [this week]. We will review the internship opportunity at that time."

How should I phrase my follow-up email?

Answer (score 2):

As you have requested to be contacted after the **date here**, I am reaching out to you to schedule my interview for the intern position at **department and/or company name**. I'm looking forward to working as an intern for **project/department/division** and contributing to the success of your organization, while gaining invaluable experience.

Looking forward to hearing back from you.

Regards,

Comment: This for an e-mail reply.  The context will be in the email already.  I see your approach, but it'd be more suited for a letter where the previous conversation is not apparent.

Comment: @codenoire I see your approach but it is more suitable for small, startup kind of companies, If the OP is going for a large and established organization, more formal approach is in order. Too casual doesn't get you anywhere. And as your comment assumes no reference to previous communications, I beg to differ. This is going to be written after hitting "reply" and the reference will be in the history of the email. No need to hammer it again.

Answer (score 1):

"Hey ____,

Hope you had a great vacation.  At your convenience, I'd like to continue our dialog on the internship opportunity.  Please respond with your availability.  Thanks!"

Simple.

Comment: I wouldn't start "Hey".  That sounds very unprofessional to me.

Comment: I don't bother trying to do "formal" emails, as it just doesn't seem the be the norm in that medium.  However, this suggestion just looks a bit too chatty and informal to me.

Comment: The traveling may also be business related and/or personal, not vacation.  I wouldn't assume.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest going for a level of formality between the other two answers, although you should take your cue from any previous communications, if you can.

Also, keep in mind that you don't know the reason for the travel - it could be pleasure (vacation), it could be personal (visiting family for good or bad reasons), it could be business (a conference), or any number of other situations. It's best to not make any assumptions about it.

I'd reply to the "please contact me" email with something like this:

> `Bobson`,
>
> As you requested, I'm reaching back out to you to discuss the internship opportunity with `your company`.  If you would like to reach me by phone, I will be available at `these times`.  I look forward to hearing from you.
>
> Thank you for this opportunity,
>
> `FST94`

A slight variation would be to replace the last sentence with something like "I look forward to hearing from you once you've had a chance to get caught up," which implies that you understand he might take a day or two to get through all his email and reply.